# "Rules" to use global or not variables

Tags: c, performance, global-variables, local-variables

I have some question to use of globals variables in the C programming language. I've never too many as theses days to don't use globals variables anymore. So,my question is: **when use or not global variables in C**? can someone give me some explanation? perfomance question,of couse,should be included.

A more specific case to help to answer the question: for example,if I have a global array that hold `struct`s,accessed by almost all functions by program,I need to get two members of this array per function call. In this case,I need to make two variables(pointers) to members in this array that I want to access. Like this `foo_t *x,*y`. It happen several times and in differents functions while program is running. In this specific case,should be `x` and `y` global or local variables(of each functions that call it)?

Some peoples argue that it's too expensive to computer's memory and of couse program perfomance.

I hope this is clear.

Comment: I think an answer can be: if you would have made it a member variable in a class, you can make it a static variable in a well defined 'module'.

Comment: @Elazar There are no classes in C. Similarly, there are no *global variables* in C.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour sure. I am sorry. I didn't know there are no classes in C. And I forgot that using the C-standard terminology is more important than understanding how to write code. Your comments do not *help*, UB. if you want to teach me something - which I am sure you can - please do so in a positive way: what *is there*, in c? and what are the rules for using it?

Comment: @Elazar Ill be thy tongue that misuses hyphens. [Global variable diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Global_variable&diff=553684985&oldid=546310440)?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour All you need to say is "when a C programmer is talking about 'global' variables, he means 'externally linkable' variables." (or something like that. feel free to correct me). The question and my answer are still perfectly clear.

Comment: @Elazar No. The issue is scope, not linkage.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour OK. Noted. from now on, when I say "global variable" in the context of C, you will know what I mean.

Comment: @Elazar If I say "your car" in the context of river, will you know what I mean? Suppose you do... Do you think others will? How can we teach them accurately, if not to use the correct terminology?

Comment: If everybody else will be using the same words with the same meaning in the same context, then yes.

Comment: @Elazar In that case, consider the definition of "global variable" in every other programming language where you can refer to a variable prior to its declaration...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Yes, natural languages are not context-insensitive.

Comment: What are your talking about here?

Comment: @Jack Global: scope or linkage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, maintainability is more important than performance. You don't describe your application very much, so I'm going to assume it isn't performance critical, and also doesn't have issues with limited stack sizes, etc. I.e. maintainability wins.

In that case, the real question is which makes the code clearer, and reduces the opportunities for errors. That's a case by case decision, though my general rule is to minimize globals, particularly globals with a more than one file scope.

If the application is multithreaded, things get even clearer - and more exciting. Every global variable must either be const, or protected by some lock. And that includes variables declared with "static". Make your life easier by only making things global if they really are shared.

Back to your case - you have some kind of big global array of data structures, and some specific positions within it. Apparently a whole bunch of routines will operate on the same positions; otherwise the question doesn't make sense. I'd do whatever makes the code most clear and readable. From your description, that's probably to make them global, but you haven't given enough detail for me to be sure. If you do make them global, for heavens sake don't call them x and y, unless those names make clear and obvious sense - e.g. if they together represent a cartesian co-ordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Although global memory and dynamic memory allocation are separate items, I tend to see paired use: lots of global memory with little allocations or little global and lots of dynamic memory usage.

Global variables (or externally linkable memory, etc.) have a valid use today in applications that are life critical.  Having worked in both Both Air Traffic Control and Life Sciences, some applications use *no* dynamically allocated memory.  There often is large global arrays instead.  Such applications can not tolerate an out of memory some time down the line and need to show that the application can handle all specified capacity on start-up.

In some micro-controller applications, again the scope and size is well known so there is no dynamic allocation and often data is shared between functions via the global space.  Even the worst case stack size is known (recursion not allowed).

In dynamic applications that need to scale with various processors, demands, etc.  good programing practice avoids global memory.  I find this coding style easier to maintain and enhance.

I do not see speed/code efficiency driving the use/non-use of global memory.  It is more of a software architecture issue.  Go with the approach the 1) meets your design goals & 2) is debug-able and maintainable.

Thought: Video memory is like global memory in that all functions and application shared this space.